# Bootstrap .container appearing wider than supposed to be

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was creating a website with Bootstrap and I realized that without adding any css or js, my websites was appearing much wider and the font size was larger than it should be.

Please see these images to see my problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQW7p.jpg and please let me know if you know what is wrong.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have zoomed your browser view nothing else is wrong with it. Just click the marked magnifying glass to fix it.[image]

Comment: nice catch, giving a +1 for that